# Scalac compiler to jar sources

Tags: scala, jar, compilation, sbt

How to get `scalac` to create a JAR file that includes the source code and/or source files in addition to class files ?

Consider `example.scala` where,

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello")
}
```

and so to generate `example.jar`,

```
scalac -d example.jar example.scala
```

With `unzip example.jar` we note no sources are included,

```
Archive:  example.jar
  inflating: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF    
  inflating: Main.class              
  inflating: Main$.class             
  inflating: Main$delayedInit$body.class
```

As commented/suggested, a solution with SBT is valued.

Comment: How are you making the jar? If you're doing it "by hand", just zip up the sources as well. If you're doing it with ant or maven or sbt, tag the question as ant or maven or sbt.

Comment: Using scalac -d name.jar name.scala

Comment: In that case you can just use the `zip` tool: `zip example.jar example.scala` will add that file to the jar. If you want something more structured I' think you'll have to use a build tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources are typically not included in the regular .jar files. They are distributed in a separate `-source.jar` instead. In sbt, you can generate the source jar with

```
> packageSrc
```